# Model Trees: M5, Cubist - What about the assumptions of the linear models being used?

Tags: r, regression, cart, assumptions

From what I understood, these models differ from CARTs for regression, mostly because they fit a linear model at the leaves of the tree instead of simply taking an average. They also "smooth" the tree by generating linear models in the intermediate steps of the tree growth process.

I have been using the R implementation of them a bit for regression getting very good results. But I wonder about the assumptions of a usual linear model? Multicolinearity, Autocorrelation, Non-Normality being violated doesnt worry people in this case?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly is the question you're asking? Can you be more specific?

Comment: If you are using linear regressions at different steps in your primary model, shouldnt you worry about the theoretical assumptions of a linear regression? For example, does everything work fine even if you have highly correlated variabes, or autocorrelated observations?

Comment: I asked for specifics because it depends on algorithm, purpose and usage. Inference most certainly needs assumptions, simple prediction may not. Also there are many ways to estimate a linear model. What do you mean by "does everything work"?  Furthermore, why do you have the impression that "people are not worried"?

Answer (score 1):

> But I wonder about the assumptions of a usual linear model? Multicolinearity, Autocorrelation, Non-Normality being violated doesnt worry people in this case?

If you add all the linear regression at different steps, is just one linear regression, why it's valid? Plot the tree, you will find that the tree model have select the best feature for the regression! so, multi-col-linearity and auto-correlation is not the problem.

Non-Normality is just for the error terms, if the prediction error of this cubist model is not normality, then you may have to try the cross-validation to tuning the parameters.